# Update Document library with "linked to document" Content type

Tags: library

I want to insert the Items in the Document Library for Content type "Linked to a Documents"

The document are in the local folder and the reference should go into the document library using "linked to a Document"

This i need to do using client obejct model.

Note: I have done all the configuration .I need to add items to the library
Need help on this.

Thank you for your help in advance
KK

Answer (score 0):

First, create document library A and add all the docs through Windows explorer. Then create a second document library B and foreach file in A:

```
    SPListItem item = file.Item;
    item["Content Type"] = "Link to a Document";
    SPFieldUrlValue itemUrl = new SPFieldUrlValue();
    itemUrl.Description = "From sample code";
    itemUrl.Url = fileLinkUrl;
    item["URL"] = itemUrl;
    //persist changes
    item.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

See : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2008/06/23/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically.aspx for creating a link to a document content type and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx for creating an item in scom

Comment: Thanks for the reply XristosK. Can you please share me the full code.I need help of how to get the file property.     Thanksfor your help,KK